# how to escape the special characters in iphone development

Tags: iphone, ipad, special-characters

Can any one guide me how to escape the special characters in iphone development,currently when i use this characters it gets me junk value,

The Following are the charaters :

""$$¢£฿¥₡€₭,

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do u want only a-z and A-Z characters??

Comment: ya either way, it should only alpha numeric value

Comment: mainly when i retrieve datas from sqlite file,it shows junk value

Comment: are you storing using right encoding scheme??

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the special characters set you want to ignore in character set.

```
NSString *oldString = @"dsfas$$$///dfa****";

NSCharacterSet *theCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-*!%$/_"];

NSString *newString = [[oldString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:theCharacterSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

NSLog(@"newString: %@",newString);
```